# SP_Admin SQL Permissions

Tags: permissions, powershell, security, sql-server, sql

I'm trying to create a web application using powershell and I'm getting a log in error with the SP_Admin account. I'm not sure if I've made a mistake when I was setting up the environment, I might have created it with the wrong account. [These](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3VDh.png) are the permission mappings I see in SQL manager. Wondering if they are correct.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBjMc.png) is the error I get in the management shell.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to check from your very informative images:

- Are you logged in as sp_admin while running the script?
- Can you open and view Central Administration?
- Do the sp_admin account have db_owner permissions on the SharePoint_AdminContent database? If not, add permission.

Answer (score 0):

CONTOSO\sp_admin lacks appropriate permissions on the SharePoint_Admin_ database. Following best practices you should use the Add-SPShellAdmin cmd-let to grant permissions to the database. Steps:

1. Logon using the farm account;
2. Launch SharePoint Management Shell using "Run as Administrator";
3. Run the following command, replacing  by the actual value

   `Get-SPDatabase | ?{$_.Name -eq "SharePoint_Admin_<Guid>"} | Add-SPShellAdmin –Username CONTOSO\sp_admin`

Reference: [Add-SPShellAdmin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607596.aspx)